# Java File file = new file not working ; cannot find symbol

Tags: java, user-interface

At the moment I'm making a HangMan GUI game in `Java`. It works  when I put the words right into the program.

But now I want to load a textfile and create a string of it, in the code below the string content.

Here on StackOverflow I have read about the use of scanners.

Now I have this code, but it won't accept the `File file = new File("woordenlijst.txt");` statement, it says at 'File' that it cannot find symbol. Can you help me? this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class galgjeGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
* Creates new form galgjeGUI
*/

private String wGalg;   // het te raden woord
private int fouten;     // globale variabele toegevoegd jonp
private int pogingen;
private int levens = 7;

public galgjeGUI() {
    initComponents();

    buttonDisableFunction();

    File file = new File("woordenlijst.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");
    String content = scan.next();
}
```

Comment: Import it; it's in `java.io`.

Comment: You forgot your import.  `import java.io.File;`

Comment: A good IDE should manage the imports for you (they get tedious very quickly otherwise).

Comment: Netbeans shift_ctrl_i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Import proper packages.

2) Handle exceptions.

3) `close()` `Scanner` object after usage.

```
import java.io.*; //import
Scanner scan = null;
try {     //handle exceptions
    File file = new File("woordenlijst.txt");
    scan = new Scanner(file);
 }
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);

 }
finally {
    scan.close(); // give up the resource.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

how does java know what you mean by `File`, there is no class called `File`, you are looking for `java.io.File` so tell compiler to use that by adding

```
import java.io.File;
```

Comment: Thank you! But know i have a problem in the next line at: new Scanner(file); it says: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
----

Comment: You will need to use a try/catch block with the accordant exception.